# In Angular 1.5, how to compile the html of a parent component from a child component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, compilation, components, parent-child

I have two angular components: `app-menuitem` and `app-menu`. app-menu has a list of app-menuitem as children but there is no transclude.

App-menuitem

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('appMenuitem', {
      transclude: false,
      controller: menuitemController,
      require: {
        parent: '^?app-menu'
      },
      bindings: {
        ...
        groupradio: '@',        
        isactive: '<', // bind to active (just init)
        ...
      },
      templateUrl: 'angular/components/simple/menuitem/menuitem.html'
    });

function menuitemController($rootScope, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var ctrl = this;

    //Default values
    ctrl.$onInit  = function () {
      if(ctrl.isactive){
        ctrl.active = true;
      }else{
        ctrl.active = false;
      }
      ctrl.selectRadioItem = function(){
          if(!ctrl.active){
             var currentMenu = this.parent.items.menu;
             var levelMenu = this.parent.items.level;
             for(var i = 0; i < currentMenu.length; i++){
                var currentMenuItem = currentMenu[i];
                if(currentMenuItem.groupradio === ctrl.groupradio){
                    if(currentMenuItem.index === ctrl.index){
                        currentMenuItem.isactive = true;
                    }else{
                        currentMenuItem.isactive = false;
                    }
                    currentMenu[i] = currentMenuItem;
                }
            }
            this.parent.items.menu = currentMenu;
            console.dir(this.parent); //<-- updates are visible but the html did not change. 
          }
          ...
```

As you can see at the end of this code, I managed to modify the parent component app-menu from this child component `app-menuitem`, but the HTML is never compiled again in this case. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Why not use data binding?

Comment: I'm using the "bindings" attribute... what do you mean ?

Comment: Would you mind posting the html for the menu items as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to change values of parent directly from children.  Instead, expose a method on the parent's controller that is invoked from the child with the needed update and let the parent handle the updates.
This allows you both to avoid more costly bindings as well as keep the control of a controller's properties in the controller itself (hence allowing you to more easily find the error source in your code). It is also more testable, if you are testing your code.

> Small Tip: For test purposes, if something doesn't update after you
>   update the model, you could always try to do $scope.$apply() after the
>   update and see if there's a `$digest` timing issue. **Do not use in
>   production unless you have to - it is costly and can easily cause run
>   time exceptions**

Comment: $scope.$apply() generate an error : '$apply already in progress' . I already tried. I will try your idea to expose the method on the parent's controller.

Comment: Thanks, I need to stay on this way. If you want a correct binding, you must pass by the parent's controller.